# Initiate a service and inject it to all controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I'm using Facebook connect to login my clients.
I want to know if the user is logged in or not.
For that i use a service that checks the user's status.

**My Service:**

```
angular.module('angularFacebbokApp')
  .service('myService', function myService($q, Facebook) {
     return {
       getFacebookStatus: function() {
          var deferral = $q.defer();
          deferral.resolve(Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
             console.log(response);
             status: response.status;
          }));
          return deferral.promise;
        }
     }
   });
```

I use a promise to get the results and then i use the $q.when() to do additional stuff.

```
angular.module('angularFacebbokApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $q, myService) {
     console.log(myService);
     $q.when(myService.getFacebookStatus())
        .then(function(results) {
            $scope.test = results.status;
      });
```

});

My problem is that i need to use the $q.when in every controller.
Is there a way to get around it? So i can just inject the status to the controller?
I understand i can use the resolve if i use routes, but i don't find it the best solution.

Comment: resolve using the response of `getloginSTatus` not the method, no need to use `when`

Comment: can u give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `$q.defer()` and `$q.when()` at all, since the `Facebook.getLoginStatus()` already return a promise.

Your service could be simpified like this:

```
.service('myService', function myService(Facebook) {
  return {
    getFacebookStatus: function() {
      return Facebook.getLoginStatus();
    }
  }
});
```

And in your controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
  myService.getFacebookStatus().then(function(results) {
    $scope.test = results.status;
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 10x, but i will still need to do the .then() on every controller to check the status. i want the status to be inserted directly when injecting myService. Is that possible?

Comment: Since it's an asynchronous operation, I don't think you can avoid that. You can rewrite it into another form, but not as easy as directly get from a service property.

Comment: no error, but the scope doesn't get updated. its like the promise doesn't get initiate in your way.

Comment: It seems like i have to return a promise in my service in order to this to work.

Comment: Where does the `Facebook` service come form?

Comment: Did you mean you have to use `$q.defer()` to create another promise for it to works?

Comment: I have to use the `$q.defer()` and return `Facebook.getLoginStatus()` as a promise

Answer (score 0):

As services in angularjs are singleton you can create new var `status` to cache facebook response. After that before you make new call to Facebook from your controller you can check if user is logged in or not checking `myService.status`

**SERVICE**

```
angular.module('angularFacebbokApp')
  .service('myService', function myService($q, Facebook) {

      var _status = {};

      function _getFacebookStatus() {
        var deferral = $q.defer();
        deferral.resolve(Facebook.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          _status = response.status;
        }));

        return deferral.promise;
      }

      return {
        status: _status,
        getFacebookStatus: _getFacebookStatus

      }
  });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
angular.module('angularFacebbokApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $q, myService) {
     console.log(myService);


     //not sure how do exactly check if user is logged 
     if (!myService.status.islogged )
     {
     $q.when(myService.getFacebookStatus())
        .then(function(results) {
            $scope.test = results.status;
      });
     }
     //user is logged in
     else
     {

         $scope.test = myService.status;
     }
  });
```

Comment: I do not need to cache the response because when Facebook checks if the user is logged in or not he does that by checking a token and that is very quick. Any way, that is not what i asked. I asked how to prevet the `$q.when` in every controller. Not how to cache the response.